# Manipulate the contents of a CSR file before signing

Tags: linux, openssl

Long story short :

- we run our own CA, we have a bunch of policies there, in some of them we DEMAND that the CSR has a SAN field
- "customers" often are unable to generate a proper CSR that contains such extension, due to old tools, etc.
- the product that we use can actually add/change the SAN field(s) just before the signing step (in the GUI, unfortunately not scriptable.....)

Question - how can i modify the CSR so that i add the SAN field (without having the private key, i ONLY have the CSR file) - from the command line, any command line, bash, powershell, whatever, or any language, python, java, etc. ?

It has to be doable, since it is doable through a GUI (commercial product so its difficult....).
From what i understand the CSR itself consists of "attributes" and public key part so i need to "detach" them, manipulate the "attributes" the way i want to and then put them back together to a valid CSR that can actually be signed.

What have i tried - play around openssl, but in the latest version it breaks the final CSR so that the -verify returns garbage and i dont want to sign that even if i could.

Any ideas are welcome !

Thanks !

BKH

Comment: I would be upset if a CA gave me a certifcate that was different from the CSR I sent.

Comment: Thats the thing, I AM changing the CSR - therefore the CA receives the exact CSR that I send. The whole thing happens before the CA even knows about the CSR. My problem is that im intermediary in the whole process so the CSR passes through my shop and this is where i want to make the change. I do have the authority to do that, i own the CA.

Comment: If your CA is applying policies requiring CSRs to contain subjectAltName, then you may have no other choice than to inform users to regenerate their CSRs.  However, if you can control your CA signing process, then yes, you can add SANs (and other cert attributes) during signing, but you cannot modify the CSR.  Your CA GUI is likely just controlling the contents of a config file.  Typically, you can create a config file containing the cert attributes you want (eg, subjectAltName), then sign the CSR using the config file.  I suggest looking for the config file that your CA GUI controls.